# How to sort a list of strings contained in one value of a selected node

Tags: xslt

Actually, i have a list of many objects of this type:

`<constraint identifier="487" optimised="false" type="CSatType1" typeSet="NOMINAL"     stations="/1/@stations.26 /1/@stations.12 /1/@stations.2 /1/@stations.11 /1/@stations.24 /1/@stations.4" > <constraint identifier="47" optimised="false" type="CSatType1" typeSet="NOMINAL"       stations="/1/@stations.26 /1/@stations.13 /1/@stations.4" >`

I'd like to get the 'stations' field sorted by the index values of the 'stations' array, like that (numerical ascending order):

`stations="/1/@stations.2 /1/@stations.4 /1/@stations.11 /1/@stations.12 /1/@stations.24 /1/@stations.26" >`

or in "ascending alphabetical order" :

`stations="/1/@stations.11 /1/@stations.12 /1/@stations.2 /1/@stations.24 /1/@stations.26 /1/@stations.4" >`

Do you think this is feasible with XSLT 1.0 ?

I just tried this :
<xsl:sort select="@stations"/>

But it appears not to be the right function for this processing.
If someone is able to publish a solution, i'm interested.
I use xsltproc on a linux box (XST 1.0)

Answer (score 1):

Given a **well-formed XML** input such as:

```
<root>
    <constraint identifier="487" optimised="false" type="CSatType1" typeSet="NOMINAL" stations="/1/@stations.26 /1/@stations.12 /1/@stations.2 /1/@stations.11 /1/@stations.24 /1/@stations.4"/>
    <constraint identifier="47" optimised="false" type="CSatType1" typeSet="NOMINAL" stations="/1/@stations.26 /1/@stations.13 /1/@stations.4"/>
</root>
```

you can use the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="constraint/@stations">
    <xsl:attribute name="stations">
        <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(., ' ')">
            <xsl:sort/>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <constraint identifier="487" optimised="false" type="CSatType1" typeSet="NOMINAL" stations="/1/@stations.11 /1/@stations.12 /1/@stations.2 /1/@stations.24 /1/@stations.26 /1/@stations.4"/>
  <constraint identifier="47" optimised="false" type="CSatType1" typeSet="NOMINAL" stations="/1/@stations.13 /1/@stations.26 /1/@stations.4"/>
</root>
```

This sorts the stations in *alphabetical* order. To sort them in *numerical* order, change:

```
        <xsl:sort/>
```

to:

```
        <xsl:sort select="substring-after(., '.')" data-type="number" />
```